# Rails 5 Bootstrap Javascript Tags Not Working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack, bootstrap-4, asset-pipeline

I'm having strange issues with Bootstrap 4 and the Rails 5 javascript tags. Everything seemed to work fine when I started on this project and I haven't made any changes to any of the js, but suddenly my collapsable navbar dropdowns stopped functioning, and I can see these errors in the console:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/packs/js/application-48ce69a491950ec17b29.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

GET http://localhost:3000/packs/js/application-48ce69a491950ec17b29.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

I am using Rails 5.2.4.1 with Ruby 2.6.3 and Bootstrap 4.

In my application.html.erb I have these javascript tags at the end of the body:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>

<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
```

But I think the problem must be contained in the tags or the files, because when I directly add these Bootstrap script tags into the application.html my dropdowns start working again:

```
<!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

So this is really confusing me and I want to make sure that the include_tag and pack_tag are actually working so that I can use the asset pipeline to keep other js files organised in folders when I need more.

This is my assets/javascripts/application.js:

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require_tree .
```

And my javascript/packs/application.js:

```
import "bootstrap";
```

And here is my config/webpack/environment.js

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require('webpack')

// Preventing Babel from transpiling NodeModules packages
environment.loaders.delete('nodeModules');

// Bootstrap 4 has a dependency over jQuery & Popper.js:
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
  })
)

module.exports = environment
```

I'm using a [Devise template made by the LeWagon bootcamp](https://github.com/lewagon/rails-templates) and am not yet confident of how everything is interacting. So here is the gemfile it generated for safe measure:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.6.3'

gem 'bootsnap', require: false
gem 'devise'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.21'
gem 'puma'
gem 'rails', '5.2.4.1'
gem 'redis'

gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 5.12.0'
gem 'sassc-rails'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'webpacker'

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'pry-byebug'
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'dotenv-rails'
end
```

Am I forgetting to include any other files that might be affecting this? Hopefully someone can spot a simple problem in here, but happy to add more info if I've missed something. This is really getting on my goat lol.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It's not good idea to have `javascript_include_tag 'application'` and `javascript_pack_tag 'application'` at the same time

If you use webpacker you don't need `app/assets/javascripts` folder

And you need to change `app/javascript/packs/application.js` to something like this:

```
require("@rails/ujs").start();
require("@rails/activestorage").start();
require("channels");
require("jquery");

import "bootstrap";
```

Comment: Ok tried this but still not working. I've changed the javascript/packs/application.js and tried it having kept the javascript_pack_tag and removed the javascript_include_tag (and vice versa), yarn & bundle installing and restarting server both times, but still neither attempts worked :/ are there any other steps I should follow?

Comment: You need to add these libraries: `yarn add bootstrap jquery popper.js`

Comment: Ahhh wonderful! That has worked. Just one error showing up in console though. How would I fix this?

Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '@rails/ujs'
    at webpackMissingModule (application.js:1)
    at Module../app/javascript/packs/application.js (application.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at bootstrap:83
    at bootstrap:83
webpackMissingModule @ application.js:1
./app/javascript/packs/application.js @ application.js:1
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:19
(anonymous) @ bootstrap:83
(anonymous) @ bootstrap:83

Comment: Maybe `require("rails-ujs").start()` without `@`

Comment: Sadly that didn't work. Tried ```yarn add rails-ujs```, didn't work. Tried yarn removing, and re-adding, but still didn't work.